# what is the proper way of passing query data to view

Tags: php, mysql

what is the best way of passing queried data to the view via function  ??
I tried to passed the mysql_query() result data and process in view and create a dynamic array in function (mysql_fetch_array()) and pass the data...I want to know what is the best way of doing this process???

Comment: The view should not have to do any work except display data.  So do your logic outside of the view and pass the data to the view.

Comment: pretend the view is a table name. when you query a table, you don't "pass query data to" a table. think of it the same way.

Comment: that means I should process inside the function and should pass a array or a object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "proper" you mean the MVC way of doing it, you'd process the data in a controller and then have the controller render a view with the final output.

If you aren't already using an MVC framework, I'd highly recommend [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/).

Comment: I am trying to create custom functions + classes to with MVC model..to complete my simple project...so I need proper understand before doing this...

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using any mvc then you should return it to a controller.make result set process in controller and pass dynamic data array to view.